# How i can execute a code every one minute in php?

Tags: php

I wanna update my database when users visiting my site , every one minute,
I use this code :

```
 $stmt = $dbConnection->prepare( "UPDATE db1_etchat_user SET alaghe=? WHERE etchat_username=?");    
$stmt->execute(array($alaghe,$username));
```

I wanna every one minute that's user visit my site ,  my columns be updated.

Excuse me for my bad English.

Comment: Need javascript/Ajax not php to do this

Comment: Use pubnum please read this http://www.pubnub.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

page2.php will call after every 1 minute

page1.php

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js" 
type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
function doUpdate() {
    $.ajax({
        url:"page2.php",
        success: function(resp) {
           setTimeout(doUpdate, 1000*60); //1000 = 1 minute
        }
    });
}
 setTimeout (   doUpdate, 1000*60 );
</script>
```

page2.php

```
$stmt = $dbConnection->prepare( "UPDATE db1_etchat_user SET alaghe=? 
                                                  WHERE etchat_username=?");    
$stmt->execute(array($alaghe,$username));
```

Comment: Thanks,But when users refresh page, database upadate,I wanna not update with refresh.

Comment: Answer updated,  it will work for your aditional requirements

Answer (score 1):

Make Ajax request to your server once per minute.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a cronjob and start the php-file you want to execute.